In Pandas how to run a FOR loop in Parallel with Dynamic variables
I have a code for a trading bot for a single currency pair. It has a:

FOR Loop as part of its program flow and
there are variables and dataframes that are initially computed
outside the FOR Loop
Which get manipulated while the FOR loop is
running and
there is also a sleep function called within the FOR loop which wait for the new bar

I want to create a code that will allow for multiple currency pairs to run with the same trading bot. However this will require 2 goals being met:

The variable names will need to be dynamic and change according to the currency pair
The FOR Loop will need to run parallelly for each currency pair.

Here is a sample code of the current concept:
#initial variables
slowma=50                    
fastma=20                    
Currpair="EURUSD.FX.CFD"
lot_size=1                  
slippagepips=2
sl=-35
tp=60



#some code will run and generate a dataframe where the historical bars upto current bar will be stored. Afterwards every new bar will be added into this dataframe as the last row

CurrPair1H #Name of Dataframe

for i in range(2000): #Begining of the FOR Loop
    
    if opentrade == True:
        #some code that manipulates the Currpair1H dataframe
        #followed by action to take
        #followed by Sleep function

    if opentrade == False:
        #some code that manipulates the Currpair1H dataframe
        #followed by action to take
        #followed by sleep function

If to make this work to trade multiple currencies then each currency will need to have its own dataframe to capture the bars specific to that dataframe and variables and all the FOR Loops will need to be run parallelly (becuase there is a sleep function in each FOR Loop)
Any ideas on how to do this?

For the dynamic external variables, you could try placing the variables in a seperate file and reading with open() within the loop. For making the currency pairs run in parallel, do they truly need to be in parallel or could they all run inside the loop? If they do need to be in parallel you could do something like this?
Lastly, it's a little hard to answer a problem in the abstract. What have you tried? What specifically is the stumbling block here?
edit: it looks like the link I posted could also let you work on variables from outside the loop, so look there too.
